# How to save desktop application state?

Tags: java, swing

I am creating an editor in java. I would like to know how to save an intermediate state in java?
For Example when user wants to save the changes done on the editor, how could it be done and also should be reloaded later.

Eg. powerpoint application is saved as .ppt or .pptx. Later the same .ppt while could be opened for further editions. I hope I am clear with my requirement.

Comment: You are using `JEditorPane` or `JTextPane`?

Comment: You should save the state in the file in a different section from the data to be edited/modified. When opening the file, you load this state and re-arrange your GUI.

Comment: Hi Luiggi could you please explain in more detail? And Vishal I am using JTextPane.

Comment: What do you need to explain? I assume you serialize the data from your file, so you need a `class GUIState implements Serializable` and store the state of your GUI items you want to save/load later, then you save the data in your file by serializing the instance of this `GUIState` and the data from the file, I assume it would be a `String` (or maybe another class that contains the `String`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the contents of `JTextPane` you can `serialize` the `DefaultStyledDocument` of `JTextPane` in a file using proper way of serialization. And when you want to load the content again you can `deserialize` the same and display it on the `JTextPane` . Consider the code given below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SaveEditor extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
     public static final String text = "As told by Wikipedia\n"
    +"Java is a general-purpose, concurrent, class-based, object-oriented computer programming language."
    + "It is specifically designed to have as few implementation "
    + "dependencies as possible. It is intended to let application developers write once, run anywhere (WORA), "
    + "meaning that code that runs on one platform does not need to be recompiled to run on another. "
    + "Java applications are typically compiled to bytecode (class file) that can run on any Java virtual "
    + "machine (JVM) regardless of computer architecture. Java is, as of 2012, one of the most popular programming "
    + "languages in use, particularly for client-server web applications, with a reported 10 million users.";
    JTextPane pane ;
    DefaultStyledDocument doc ;
    StyleContext sc;
    JButton save;
    JButton load;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    SaveEditor se = new SaveEditor();
                    se.createAndShowGUI();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception evt) {}
    }
    public void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        setTitle("TextPane");
        sc = new StyleContext();
        doc = new DefaultStyledDocument(sc);
        pane = new JTextPane(doc);
        save = new JButton("Save");
        load = new JButton("Load");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(save);panel.add(load);
        save.addActionListener(this);load.addActionListener(this);
        final Style heading2Style = sc.addStyle("Heading2", null);
        heading2Style.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.red);
        heading2Style.addAttribute(StyleConstants.FontSize, new Integer(16));
        heading2Style.addAttribute(StyleConstants.FontFamily, "serif");
        heading2Style.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Bold, new Boolean(true));
        try 
        {
            doc.insertString(0, text, null);
            doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, 1, heading2Style, false);
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Exception when constructing document: " + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(pane));
        getContentPane().add(panel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setSize(400, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        if (evt.getSource() == save)
        {
            save();
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == load)
        {
            load();
        }
    }
    private void save()//Saving the contents .
    {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(".");
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Save");
        int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(this);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
        {
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            if (file != null)
            {
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                ObjectOutputStream os = null;
                try
                {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                    os.writeObject(doc);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Saved successfully!!","Success",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (fos != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            fos.close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex){}

                    }
                    if (os != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            os.close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex){}

                    }
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please enter a fileName","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
    private void load()//Loading the contents
    {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(".");
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Open");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
        {
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            if (file!= null)
            {
                FileInputStream fin = null;
                ObjectInputStream ins = null;
                try
                {
                    fin = new FileInputStream(file);
                    ins = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
                    doc = (DefaultStyledDocument)ins.readObject();
                    pane.setStyledDocument(doc);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Loaded successfully!!","Success",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (fin != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            fin.close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex){}

                    }
                    if (ins != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ins.close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex){}

                    }
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please enter a fileName","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Vishal. and sorry for replying so late.

Comment: Hi Vishal, Can this be done on JPanel. MY Panel has lots of buttons, images, labels and other stuffs. Can I save them all?

Answer (score 2):

The [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) API with user preferences; most recently edited files, per file maybe timestamp + cursor position, GUI settings.